# How do I stack under an element which has a z-index of auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For the below script, how do I position `<div id="blocker">` beneath `<div id="mceu_13" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel">` without setting the `z-index` of `#mceu_13`?  As seen, the `z-indez` of `#mceu_13` is `auto`.

http://jsbin.com/bujixoyoga

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>jQueryUI Dialog Overlay</title>
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #blocker{margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.4; position: absolute;}
        #dialog{position: relative;}
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#editor',
                setup: function(ed) {
                    ed.on('init', function(e) {
                        e.target.hide();
                    });
                }
            });
            $(function(){
                $('#edit').click(function() {
                    var dialog=$("#dialog").parent().append($('<div>',{id:'blocker'}));
                    console.log(dialog,$(this).next(),$(this).next().css('z-index'))
                    //$(this).next().css('z-index',parseInt(dialog.css('zIndex'), 10)+1)
                    tinymce.get('editor').show();
                });
                $("#open").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 400,
                    width       : 400, 
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        $('#editor').html('Some data obtained from the DB.');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='open'>Open</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="dialog title">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="edit">Edit</a>
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a negative z-index:

```
#blocker {
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: actually I don't really know the specifics. It could be related to absolute positioning, but that's just a wild guess. I just figured that #blocker needed a lower z-index than the 2 sibling divs. If you add z-index: -1 to those 2, then #blocker will need z-index of -2 or lower.

Comment: apparently, by default an overlapping element gets stacked on top the previous one, even if absolutely positioned. So it was simply a matter of getting the 3rd div a lower stacking order. Info and samples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Actually, not perfect as it produces inconsistent results.  Probably better off explicitly setting z-index on the element I wish to stack under.

Comment: yeah, the z-index for the other elements was just to explain z-index. Go with whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#blocker{
 z-index: -1;
 }
```

This works because #mceu_13 is set to auto which means that element gets z-index from its parent and  has  default z-index:0.

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation (but next time please don't post it as an answer)

Comment: I was not allowed to comment there so I just answer here.